# Trouble hiding "dropdown" menu

Tags: jquery, html, menu, jquery-animate, dropdown

I've made a "dropdown" menu. It works perfectly when I open/show it but I can't close/hide it?

```
<div class="expand-menu">
    <div class="cities">
        <!-- menu content -->
    </div>
</div>
<ul>
    <li class="choose-btn">
        <a href="">City name</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```js
var city_btn = $(".choose-btn");
var city_active = $(".choose-btn a");
var Expand_menu = (".expand-menu");
var City_cont = (".cities");
```

Here I open/show my "dropdown" menu (works)

```
$(city_btn).click(function() {
    $(Expand_menu).animate({top: "0"}, 'normal');
    $(Expand_menu).fadeIn({queue: false, duration: 'normal'});
    $(City_cont).fadeIn("normal");
    $(city_active).addClass("choose-btn-active");
    return false;
});
```

Here I would like to close/hide it

```
$(city_btn).click(function() {
    $(Expand_menu).animate({top: "10px"}, 'normal');
    $(Expand_menu).fadeOut({queue: false, duration: 'normal'});
    $(City_cont).fadeOut("normal");
    $(city_active).removeClass("choose-btn-active");        
    return false;
});
```

Comment: You missed the `$` symbol in `(".expand-menu");` and `(".cities")`. Also, all your vars are already jQuery object so you don't need to call the `$` function again: `$(Expand_menu)` -> just `Expand_menu.animate...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using like this,

```
var city_btn = $(".choose-btn");
var city_active = $(".choose-btn a");
var Expand_menu = $(".expand-menu");
var City_cont = $(".cities");

city_btn.click(function() {

if(city_active.hasClass("choose-btn-active")){
   Expand_menu.animate({top: "10px"}, 'normal');
   Expand_menu.fadeOut({queue: false, duration: 'normal'});
   City_cont.fadeOut("normal");
   city_active.removeClass("choose-btn-active");

   return false;

   }else{

     Expand_menu.animate({top: "0"}, 'normal');
     Expand_menu.fadeIn({queue: false, duration: 'normal'});
     City_cont.fadeIn("normal");
     city_active.addClass("choose-btn-active");

      return false;

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var city_btn = $(".choose-btn");
var city_active = $(".choose-btn a");
var Expand_menu = $(".expand-menu");
var City_cont = $(".cities");
```

Try It Once